# Open-Source Diff Tool for C#

Tags: open-source, c#, diff

I'm looking for an open-source diff tool that I can integrate in my C# code.

I am comparing two strings of text and want to render my output to look similar to the Stack Exchange diff tool:

**inline:**

> [image]

**side-by-side:**

> [image]

Stack Exchange uses [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/), which seems to do a very nice job comparing changes, but I am looking for something that is free.

I found a few posts on Stack Overflow talking about diff tool recommendations, yet these questions are off topic for Stack Overflow and were closed, so the answers given are very likely not maintained. Also, all these questions were posted a few years ago, and so the technology suggested may no longer be the best software available.

Here are the SO questions for reference:

- [Diff tool that can be integrated into a C# app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505851/diff-tool-that-can-be-integrated-into-a-c-sharp-app) - asked in 2012
- [Does anyone know of an advanced diff tool for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161216/does-anyone-know-of-an-advanced-diff-tool-for-c) - asked in 2009
- [Any decent text diff/merge engine for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138331/any-decent-text-diff-merge-engine-for-net) - asked in 2008

These are some of the suggestions posted, yet I don't know if they are still recommended or if better technology now exists:

- https://code.google.com/archive/p/csdiff/ - seems like Google stopped supporting this in 2015
- https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex
- http://winmerge.org/downloads/ - source was last updated in 2012
- https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/ - last release was in 2012

Comment: Would you mind telling us what you eventually selected?

Comment: @RenniePet I think I ended up using a version of the Google Diff, Match, Patch library, however, I have since moved on from that job and can't check. I do remember though, I wasn't thrilled with the comparison algorithm results of whatever code I ended up with, and that is why I never added it as an answer. Although I am no longer looking for a solution, it would be nice if someone can still suggest a tool they use that works well, so others can refer to this question as a reference in the future.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but I recently wrote a C# library and accompanying console program which compares 2 strings and shows the difference in 2 html-files.

It can be found [here](https://github.com/thieupepijn/TextComparer). Hopefully someone reading this question finds it useful.

Comment: I'm no longer working on this project, but always appreciate an answer and hopefully someone else will find it useful. Just a tip, it may be helpful if you add some sort of screenshot or demo to your GitHub repo README.

Comment: Although you might not need it yourself anymore, can you mark my/this post as the answer if you think it answered the question ? Both for future readers of this question and for me to earn my kudos. By the way, I followed up your suggestion and added some screenshots to to the repository.

Comment: I can't feel comfortable accepting an answer that I haven't tested since I have no way of knowing if it really can accomplish what I asked in the question. I've tried multiple diff tools in the past, and each one had its pros and cons, so I have no way of knowing where your's falls since I am no longer working on the project and am not testing your library on actual text. If your answer does help other people in the future though, I'm sure you will get more upvotes. And the screenshots definitely help demonstrate if your library is something worth trying.

Comment: I can confirm the library works for me so far. Thanks much!!!